# codeigniter $this->db->where(); custom string problem

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im trying to select some values using a custom string. below is my code

```
  $this->db->from('posted');
  $st="infor='rent' AND (typeq='in' OR typeq='out')";
  $this->db->where($st);  
  $q = $this->db->get();
```

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> ```
> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column ‘infor=‘rent’’ in ‘where clause’
> SELECT * FROM (`posted_ads`) WHERE `infor=‘rent’` AND (typeq=‘in’
>  OR typeq=‘out’)
> Filename: C:\wamp\www\parklot\system\database\DB_driver.php
> Line Number: 330
> ```

i think the problem is coz of

```
WHERE `infor='rent'`
```

when i manualy execute this code it works perfectly.

```
WHERE infor='rent'
```

how do i get rid of

```
``
```

because its automatically added

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add a third parameter to the `where()` and set it to `FALSE`

```
  $this->db->from('posted');
  $st="infor='rent' AND (typeq='in' OR typeq='out')";
  $this->db->where($st, NULL, FALSE);  
  $q = $this->db->get();
```

> `$this->db->where()` accepts an optional third parameter. If you set it to `FALSE`, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks.

[CodeIgniter Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#select)

Comment: If you do similar things often, useful to create a function which add ticks around the table names and fields - or write a simple wrapper-function which calls `db->where` with proper ticks (with `false` third parameter of course).

Comment: It's a shame that this isn't in the docs here. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: @user1253085 It's in there. You must've overlooked.

Comment: I see it now.  At the very, very bottom.  I'm used to docs defining function usage and available params and options before showing examples.

Answer (score 0):

While the solution works I wanna add: Be careful! You need to secure your query and escape all values! If you like to use the Query Builder

```
$q = $this->db->select('*')->from('posted_ads')
    ->where('infor', 'rent')
    ->or_group_start()
            ->where('typeq', 'in')
            ->where('typeq', 'out')
    ->group_end()
->get();
```

This way Codeigniter takes care of proper escaping.