# Weird Codeigniter query escaping

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

Issue is that string in active record statement gets escaped when string contains a combination of words 'or' and 'like'. Here is the code I use

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->where('phrase', $phrase);
$this->db->from('phrases');
$ret    = $this->db->get();
```

This works for normal strings but fail when $phrase encounters a string like
'Click on the Event or Booking Code you would like to use.'
 where 'or' and 'like' are present as words.

Resulting query will be like

```
SELECT `id` FROM `phrases` WHERE `phrase` = 'Click on the Event or `Booking Code you` `would` like to use.'
```

I can't disable escaping as this comes handy for other strings.

Comment: I personally find CI's active record API more trouble than it's worth. As you're discovering, it mangles some stuff and can't handle complex queries. You can always just bypass it and use `$db->query('sql here')`

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Utkanos. Seems like this is the only solution clubbed with manually escaping the string using $this->db->escape($phrase)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a third parameter to your where clause to escape values.

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->where('phrase', $phrase, FALSE);
$this->db->from('phrases');
$ret    = $this->db->get();
```

From the [manual](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where#CI_DB_query_builder::where):

> where($key[, $value = NULL[, $escape = NULL]])
>
> Parameters:
> $key (mixed) – Name of field to compare, or associative array
>
> $value (mixed) – If a single key, compared to this value
>
> $escape (bool) – Whether to escape values and identifiers

More info in this post on [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547731/codeigniter-this-db-where-custom-string-problem).

Comment: I tried that but at the cost of no escaping. As you can see from my query , I already get an escaped output at unwanted places.